# How can I mimic web browsing via a cell phone?

Tags: browser, browser-addons

Some online retailers offer special deals to people who browse their sites or make orders with a mobile phone.

Is there a way I can mimic a cell phone using a desktop computer so it looks like I am using a cell phone to connect to the web site?

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: there are many ways they might choose to determine what platform you are on, and each of them will have a different solution, so don't expect a one-size-fits-all answer.

Comment: @FrankThomas I understand the complexity, that's why the question exists. If this was a simple problem, I would not have needed to ask here.

Comment: @TylerDurden - You will need to reduce the scope of the question.  How you change the reported agent within IE11, Edge, Firefox, Chrome are all well documented.  Its not clear the reason, changing the view agent, isn't enough.  You should edit your question, and provide specific information, in what you are trying to do and the reason simply changing the view agent isn't enough.

Comment: @Ramhound This is not an open ended question. There is a limited set of possible information in the browser header that will indicate whether the browser is mobile-based. I am interested in knowing a way to generate such headers. This will probably require more than just user agent switching. I need someone with experience in the area to answer the question.

Comment: @TylerDurden - "I need someone with experience in the area to answer the question." - I actually have extensive experience in this area.  Case in point, I can view the Microsoft website that allows you to download an ISO for Windows 10, but its only offered to a browser not running on a Windows machine.  This means if I configure my browser to present myself as a mobile browser (Windows Phone, OS X Safari, ect) I am presented that download link instead of the link to the Media Creation Tool which is presented to all Windows based browsers

Comment: **I am clearly not the SME for you.**  So i wish you good luck, I encourage you to work on being nice to everyone in the community, instead of telling them in a passive agressive way that they don't know what they are talking about.  Since I am more curious then a cat, "This will probably require more than just user agent switching.", why do you believe thats the case?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `User-Agent` http header to somethink browser-like, e.g.: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the user agent of your browser to mimic browsing from a mobile device.

If you're using Chrome browser, below are two options you can try out to change the user agent:

1. User-Agent Switcher extension for Chrome: http://useragentswitcher.org/index.html
2. Follow this guide which shows how to change the user agent without installing any extensions: http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/